# Class argument variable automatically comma separated,

Tags: python, aws-lambda

Hi,

I'm passing below variable to a function inside a class

ba4dfb43-46a6-44ec-9249-18bdf6621b01

but when I call it inside the class it is comma separated. like below format.

('b', 'a', '4', 'd', 'f', 'b', '4', '3', '-', '2', '8', '7', '5', '-', '4', 'b', '8', 'd', '-', 'b', 'a', '5', 'd', '-', '1', '8', 'b', 'd', 'f', '6', '6', '2', '1', 'b', '0', '1', '\n')

Can someone tell me why it is happening?

`for item in run_list:
            print('item passing to processes1')
            print(item)  # item is printing properly here and type is str
            p1 = Process(target=runclass.crowdstrike, args=(item))`

Class code is follows

`# ========================== Main Class =============================    
class VolumesParallel(object):
# ============================= Multiprocessing CS CODE ======================================
    def strike(self, *item):
        print('inside the class')
        print(item)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a comma when you passing item to args. In python if have one item inside circle brckets, it is not a tuple, it is just item inside brackets. So tu make it like tuple you need to add a comma after item